# checkbox list in ionic

Tags: checkbox, ionic-framework

I write this code for add contact to group.
how i make line by line checkbox?
this is in line checkbox list.

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="employee in employees" >
          <label class="checkbox">
              <input  ng-model="checkGroups[employee.id]" type="checkbox">
          </label>
            {{employee.name}}
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

[image]

Comment: check this http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/Enmaw

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="employee in employees track by $index ">
          <label class="checkbox">
              <input name={{$index}} ng-model="checkGroups[employee.id]" type="checkbox">
          </label>
            {{employee.name}}
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: this is not Work.Please Show Image